# How to await for RequestAccessAsync?

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await

I'm trying to create a listener to Windows notifications, following the steps on [this example on Micr*soft's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2016/05/26/notification-listener-documentation-windows-10/)

The very second code snip, that supposedly gets the user authorization, doesn't compile saying:

```
error CS4033: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. 
Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.
```

Although I am not familiar with C#'s async/await mechanism, the method is question is called RequestAccess**Async**, and the source opened by Visual Studio have a `[RemoteAsync]` above the method.

This is the full code snip:

```
// Get the listener
UserNotificationListener listener = UserNotificationListener.Current;

// And request access to the user's notifications (must be called from UI thread)
UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus accessStatus = await listener.RequestAccessAsync();

switch (accessStatus)
{
    // This means the user has granted access.
    case UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus.Allowed:

        // Yay! Proceed as normal
        break;

    // This means the user has denied access.
    // Any further calls to RequestAccessAsync will instantly
    // return Denied. The user must go to the Windows settings
    // and manually allow access.
    case UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus.Denied:

        // Show UI explaining that listener features will not
        // work until user allows access.
        break;

    // This means the user closed the prompt without
    // selecting either allow or deny. Further calls to
    // RequestAccessAsync will show the dialog again.
    case UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus.Unspecified:

        // Show UI that allows the user to bring up the prompt again
        break;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: where is your method signature? did you mark it as `async`?

Comment: You need to show more code, you need to show the method that holds your code example,

Comment: Thanks guys that was the issue. This code was in a class constructor, that (as I just learned, can't be async)

Comment: @RSFalcon7 see my updated answer for a work around for running async code in a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the full code snippet... you need to mark the calling method as **[async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx)**.

```
public async Task<ReturnType> MyMethod()
{
    // Get the listener
    UserNotificationListener listener = UserNotificationListener.Current;

    // And request access to the user's notifications (must be called from UI thread)
    UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus accessStatus = await listener.RequestAccessAsync();
}
```

To do this in a constructor, as per your comments, I would use [Nito.AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) and [`AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext) like this:

```
public class MyProgram
{
    public MyProgram()
    {
        UserNotificationListenerAccessStatus accessStatus = AsyncContext.Run(listener.RequestAccessAsync);
    }
}
```